# In VS Code with Volar, how can I view all implementations of a Vue 3 component?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, volar

So if I have a `<script setup>` component that's used in multiple places in my app, how can I view all it's usages?

The `Go to Implementations` or `Go to References` options don't do anything, so the only way I have currently is text searching for the import declarations across the whole project, then looking for the `<Component>` tags per file manually.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1724

You can use find file references in right click menu or command palette.

[image]

Comment: When using unplugin-vue-componentsthe file is not directly referenced in other files but in the components.d.ts. Is there something else ?